# Prevent DIV height impacting position of DIVs below

Tags: html, css

Please consider the problem posed by the following code:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='topLeft' style='background-color:red;float:left'>Top Left</div>
    <div id='topRight' style='background-color:green;float:left;font-size:x-large'>Top Right</div>
    <div id='clearDiv' style='clear:both;'></div>
    <div id='bottom' style='background-color: yellow;'>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

In [a fiddle I've created](https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/xred4scd/), this produces the following result:
[image]

The problem with this, as far as the page I'm working on is concerned, is that space above the yellow `div` labelled ***bottom***, caused by the additional height of the green `div` (Top Right). I want the yellow `div` to be right up against the bottom of the red `div` (Top Left), regardless of the height of the green `div`.

Now, this is easily enough fixed by using positioning, as follows ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/0416syet/)):

```
<div id='container' style='position:relative'>
    <div id='topLeft' style='background-color:red;float:left;width:100px'>Top Left</div>
    <div id='topRight' style='background-color:green;float:left;font-size:x-large;position:absolute;left:100px;z-index:-1'>Top Right</div>
    <div id='clearDiv' style='clear:both;'></div>
    <div id='bottom' style='background-color: yellow;'>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Which produces the following result:
[image]

That's exactly what I want. Unfortunately, because the green ***Top Right*** `div` is now positioned absolutely, I now have to specify its left position to ensure that it still appears to the right of the red (Top Left) `div`.

In the application I'm writing, I'm having to expend a lot of effort to continually position the equivalent of this green `div` to the right of the red `div`, when no effort would be required at all if it didn't have the `position:absolute` attribute. Without that, it'd just naturally appear after the red `div`, as it did in the result of the first code sample.

So my question is: **Is there a way to achieve the same result as I have with my solution - that is, the top of the yellow `div` being up against the bottom of the red `div` - without adding `position:absolute` to the green div?**

***Update*** following Ned Rockson's answer, I should add that explicitly setting the height of any of these divs or a wrapper div isn't possible either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#topLeft {
  background-color: red;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;  
}
#topRight {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: x-large;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em; /* THIS IS  THE ONLY "MANUAL" SETTING */
}
#bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='topLeft'>
      Top Left
    </div>
    <div id='topRight'>
      Top Right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='bottom'>
    Bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution requires you to "manually" set the width of the `topRight` element, but heights are automatically handled by the CSS.

Comment: This is very nice, I really need to get to grips with flex.

Comment: @PhilipStratford yeah Flexbox has largely made `float` obsolete and is very powerful; exactly what CSS needed for so long. This is my canonical reference for all things flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I was just reading that when you replied! Out of interest, how would you achieve this same outcome when it was the top-left div that was the taller one? Just swapping them over doesn't work as suddenly the height of the taller div seems to define the height that all of the divs in that row should have.

Comment: This works by taking the taller element out of the document layout flow (`topRight` in the original case). The taller element must be positioned absolutely to achieve this. When you position an element absolutely in this case, we use the `topLeft` element as a "hook" back into the document flow, which allows us to position `topRight` `relative` to `topLeft`. I hope that helps your understanding of things. If not I suggest, reading up on CSS positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the top left and top right divs in a div with height set and `overflow` set to `hidden`. It's not a very elegant approach because the outer div's height is set, but it works for this particular problem.

```
<html>
  <body>
      <div id='container' style='position:relative'>
          <div style='overflow:hidden; height:18px'>
              <div id='topLeft' style='background-color:red;float:left;width:100px'>Top Left</div>
              <div id='topRight' style='background-color:green;float:left;font-size:x-large'>Top Right</div>
          </div>
          <div id='clearDiv' style='clear:both;'></div>
          <div id='bottom' style='background-color: yellow;'>Bottom</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer, and you're right, it does address the problem as posed. Unfortunately, setting a height on the outer div isn't an option either in practice, as you'd probably expect. I'll update my question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the upper two DIVs bottom-aligned despite their different height, you can assign them this instead of floats:

```
#topLeft, #topRight {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  }
```

Here is the complete code:

```css
#topLeft, #topRight {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='topLeft' style='background-color:red;'>Top Left
    </div><div id='topRight' style='background-color:green;font-size:x-large'>Top Right</div>
    <div id='clearDiv'></div>
    <div id='bottom' style='background-color: yellow;'>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Note that I moved the closing `</div>` of the `.topLeft` element into the next line to avoid any spaces and linebreaks in the code.

---

Alternative solution using flex:

If you need topLeft and topRight to have the same height, you can wrap them in a parent container and assign `display: flex` to this container:

```css
#wrapTop {
  display: flex;
  }
```

```html
 <div id='container'>
   <div id="wrapTop">
        <div id='topLeft' style='background-color:red;'>Top Left</div>
        <div id='topRight' style='background-color:green;font-size:x-large'>Top Right</div>
    </div>        <div id='clearDiv'></div>
        <div id='bottom' style='background-color: yellow;'>Bottom</div>
    </div>
```